# Fortran: Gradient method for minimum of a 2D-function

Tags: optimization, fortran, fortran90, genetic-algorithm

I made this simple program to compute the minimum of a goal function using the gradient method. I test it for a simple 1D function (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) and it's work very well giving to me the exact position of the minimum.

I generalize it to a 2D function: x^4+2y^4 which as only one zero in (0,0) as follow:

```
real*8 function cubic(xvect_old,n)
   real(8), dimension(n) :: xvect_old

 cubic = 4.d0*(xvect_old(1)**3.d0)+8.d0*(xvect_old(2)**3.d0)     
!cubic = 4.d0*(xvect_old(1)**3.d0)-9.d0*(xvect_old(1)**2.d0)

end function cubic

program findmin
implicit none
   integer, parameter :: n=2
   integer :: i,j,m
   real(8) :: cubic
   real(8), dimension(n) :: xvect,xvect_old
   real(8) :: eps,max_prec
   m=30
   eps = 0.01d0 ! step size
   xvect_old =0.d0
   xvect(1) = 2.2d0 ! first guess
   xvect(2) = 3.1d0
   max_prec = 1e-16

  do while ( abs(xvect(1) - xvect_old(1)) > max_prec .and. &
              & abs(xvect(2) - xvect_old(2)) > max_prec)
   xvect_old(1:2) = xvect(1:2)
   xvect(1:2) = xvect_old(1:2) - eps*cubic(xvect_old,n)
  end do 

  print*, "Local minimum occurs at : ", xvect(1:2)

end program findmin
```

But it give to me, also if I am very near to the correct position (let's say, thanking as first guess (1.2,1.1) )  some large non correct solutions:

> (-0.5017  ;     0.3982)

Is the method implemented wrong or there is some lack in my understanding how accurate the method is? I know there are more advanced methods like genetic algorithm which are, maybe, faster but are they also easy to implement?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: FWIW `real*8` is not the same as `real(8)` aand neither is guaranteed to be the same as `double precision`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cubic` is supposed to return the gradient and thus must be a vector.

Try the following:

```
module functions
implicit none
contains
function cubic(x,n) result(g)
integer, intent(in) :: n
real*8, dimension(n), intent(in) :: x
real*8, dimension(n) :: g
    g =(/ 4.d0*(x(1)**3.d0), 8.d0*(x(2)**3.d0) /)
end function cubic

end module

program SOGradient
use functions
implicit none
integer, parameter :: n=2
integer :: i,j,m
real(8), dimension(n) :: xvect,xvect_old
real(8) :: eps,max_prec
m=30
eps = 0.01d0 ! step size
xvect_old =(/ 0.d0, 0d0 /)
! first guess
xvect = (/ 2.2d0, 3.1d0 /)
max_prec = 1e-12

do while ( MAXVAL(ABS(xvect-xvect_old))>max_prec )
    xvect_old = xvect
    xvect = xvect_old - eps*cubic(xvect_old,n)
end do 

print*, "Local minimum occurs at : ", xvect

end program SOGradient
```

Of course the closer you get to the minimum, the smaller the step so the convergence is really slow. I would suggest using a newton raphson type method to find where the gradient is zero.

So to find the minimum of `f(x,y)` find the gradient `g(x,y)=[gx,gy]=[df/dx,df/dy]` and the gradient of the gradient `h(x,y) = [[ dgx/dx, dgx/dy],[dgy/dx, dgy/dy]]`

Now you iterate with

```
[x,y] -> [x,y] - h(x,y)^(-1)*g(x,y)
```

In you case `f(x,y) = x^4+2*y^2`, `g=[4*x^3, 8*y^3]` and `h=[[12*x^2,0],[0,24*y^2]]`

```
[x,y] -> [x,y] - [x/3,y/3]
```

which obviously has a solution in (0,0), but converges there much faster.